# MTM 2012 - Getting selected Test Steps while creating a bug from MTM

Tags: testing, microsoft-test-manager

I am using option "Create Bug" from MTM ,if test case is getting failed at particular step.
As a result , Bug Repro steps shows entire test steps.

Sometime all these steps are not required to mention in bug and act as redundant information.

Do we have any option to remove steps which are not desired while creating a bug from MTM?

Answer (score 0):

If some of the test steps are not required, then you need to create a smaller test case, that includes only the steps required to cause the bug.

Now, on the other hand, MTM 2013 has support for "exploratory testing". You can work with the application, trying different things, without a test case. Eventually, if you find a bug, you can choose which of your actions should be included with the bug report.

Comment: Thanks John,You take example where test case can not be further divided, for same user action , objective A,B passed but C got failed then I want to exclude A,B validation steps out of reported bug

Comment: No, actually, I don't. If you have a test case which has failed, then your developers can run the exact same test case that QA has run. If a smaller test case would have failed (A, B not necessary), then create a new test case with only step C, and write the bug based on that. It is important that your QA and developers run the same test cases.

Comment: Also, I would _create_ the test case such that all of the steps are necessary in order to lead to the steps which demonstrate the bug. Any steps which are not necessary should be left out of the test case from which the bug is created.

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is impossible to remove particular steps while creating a bug.

Actually, I think it's good that it is impossible... I can just write in the bug description "you can ignore the steps up to XXX" but developer can still see what I really done since it could be that you **have** to run all the steps (all some of them) in order to reproduce the issue (and you are just not aware of it ;-) )